# How to boot into command line interface

Tags: linux, pop-os

I think I inadvertantly edited some system files, and now my PC (pop os linux) won't fully boot.

I get to enter the password for the disk encryption, but I don't get to the login screen. I suspect it's an issue with an Xorg file.

**Is there a way to boot into a windowless session?** So that I can try to fix it from the command line.

With F11 I can select some boot options, but the recovery one is not working, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for that, I was able to solve my problem! Feel free to turn it into an answer

Answer (score 1):

After (semi-successful) boot, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> etc. to access `tty1` or `tty2`, or `tty3` and so on.

One of them may be taken by your (messed up) GUI environment, but (assuming only the GUI is messed up) others should allow you to log in and start a shell.

When out of GUI, you may be able to switch ttys with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> etc. (no need for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>).